# Javascript function not working for Acc No

Tags: javascript, java

In my JSP page script function is not working.why is it?
I have many messages in single JSP and for every message I have table having different columns names and I need to validate that too.

```
<script>
function validate()
{
    var acc=document.getElementById("accno").value;
    var date=document.getElementById("datefrom").value;
    var date1=document.getElementById("dateto").value;

    if(acc==null){
        alert("Account Number Should Not be Empty");
        return false;
    }
    if(acc>=9 && acc<=9){
        alert("Enter valid Account Number");
    }
    if(isNaN(acc))
    {alert('Enter the Numeric value');
    return false;
    }
    if (date=="" && date1==""){
        alert("Please Select Date");
    }
}
</script>
```

my jsp I am trying to validate account number

```
<form action="BankingController" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
<div class="content">

<%String Error=(String)request.getAttribute("error");%>
<%String deposit=(String)request.getAttribute("deposit"); %>
<%String transaction=(String)request.getAttribute("transaction"); %>
<%String transfererror=(String)request.getAttribute("transfererror"); %>
<%String statement=(String)request.getAttribute("statement"); %>
<br>

<%String message=(String)request.getAttribute("message");%>
<center>
<br>
<%if(Error!=null){ %>
<center><h1>Withdraw Details</h1></center>
<span style="color: red">   <%=Error %></span>

<table >
<tr><td>Acc No  :</td><td><input type="text" name="accno" id="accno"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="Submit"  class="button" name="action" value="WithdrawDetails"></td></tr>
</table>
<%} %>
```

Comment: Not working in what way?

Comment: If I am not giving any values for Acc No it is showing HTTP Status 500 - For input string: ""...But I did script function for that

Comment: HTTP Status 500 means an application error. Check your logs, find your stacktrace. My guess is there's an error in the BankingController

Comment: But why my script is not working

Comment: Show us the Java code. `For input string: ""` is a message usually used by `NumberFormatException`, and means an empty string was to be parsed...

Comment: It should not move to java code because if I am giving empty string it should enter into script function and it should show that alert message and should return false.